# Trying to use the demo but not able to figure out what is wrong

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to use your demo at https://github.com/petrbroz/bim360-issue-editor/tree/7d0c080e6b33fd2098030136bef16da71ec33470#readme to fulfill a real problem at work.

I have added the custom integration under my BIM 360 Account. But I am still seeing the error on the app page. Can you please suggest? Did I miss anything?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwqpG.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piCXr.png)

Comment: Did you mean to post this as an Issue on that github repository? https://github.com/petrbroz/bim360-issue-editor/issues

Comment: finally, after removing and re-adding the client id, it started to work. It might be some invalid letter with when the client id is input.